# Creating multiple textFields programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Here is a link with with an image of the big button.
The red image with number 0 over it is a textField where my problem is present.

[image]

I have a scroll View having 12 (big)buttons that were created programmatically. On those buttons u have added 12 more buttons(one small button on each big button) and the code was working fine. But when i tried to add 12 textFields as subview, one on each big button programmatically i am unable to get twelve textFields. I end up getting just one textField and that too always on the last button of a particular row of big buttons. I am unable to identify the issue. Here is my code to create the big buttons, small buttons and the textFields on them.

```
 - (void)createButtons{
 NSUInteger i;
 int xCoord=54;
 int yCoord=10;
 int buttonWidth=292;
 int buttonHeight=266;
 int buttonGap = 80;
 int count=1;
 UIButton *aButton;

 //forCartButton
 int xCoordForCart=230;
 int yCoordForCart=200;
 int buttonWidthForCart=35;
 int buttonHeightForCart=36;
 int buttonGapForCart = 160;
 UIButton *aButtonForCart;

  //for textField
  int xCoordForTextField=aButton.frame.origin.x-30;
  int yCoordForTextField=aButton.frame.origin.y+210;
  int WidthForTextField=50;
  int HeightForTextField=30;
  int GapForTextField= 160;

  UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc]init];
  [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
  textField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
  textField.text=@"24";
  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;


    for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
      {
      aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      aButtonForCart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     if(count >=1 && count<=3){
         //for item button
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
        xCoord=xCoord+323;


        //for cart button
        aButtonForCart.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordForCart, yCoordForCart,buttonWidthForCart,buttonHeightForCart);
        xCoordForCart=xCoordForCart+2;

        //for textField
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordForTextField+50,yCoordForTextField,WidthForTextField,HeightForTextField);
        xCoordForTextField = xCoordForTextField+10;
        [aButton addSubview:textField];
        [aButton bringSubviewToFront:textField];

        if(count == 3){
            xCoord=54;
            xCoordForCart=230;
            xCoordForTextField = 230;
        }

    }else if (count >3 && count<=6){
        yCoord=buttonHeight+buttonGap;
        aButton.frame= CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
        xCoord=xCoord+323;

         //for cart button
        yCoordForCart=buttonHeightForCart+buttonGapForCart;
        aButtonForCart.frame= CGRectMake(xCoordForCart, yCoordForCart,buttonWidthForCart,buttonHeightForCart);
        xCoordForCart=xCoordForCart+2;

        //for TextField
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordForTextField+50,yCoordForTextField,WidthForTextField,HeightForTextField);
        xCoordForTextField = xCoordForTextField+10;
        [aButton addSubview:textField];
        [aButton bringSubviewToFront:textField];

        if(count == 6){
            xCoord=54;
            xCoordForCart=230;
            xCoordForTextField = 230;

        }

    }else if (count >6 && count<=9){
        yCoord=buttonHeight+buttonHeight+buttonGap+30;
        aButton.frame= CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
        xCoord=xCoord+323;

        //for cart button
        yCoordForCart=buttonHeightForCart+buttonHeightForCart+buttonGapForCart-30;
        aButtonForCart.frame= CGRectMake(xCoordForCart, yCoordForCart,buttonWidthForCart,buttonHeightForCart);
        xCoordForCart=xCoordForCart+2;

        //for textField
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordForTextField+50,yCoordForTextField,WidthForTextField,HeightForTextField);
        xCoordForTextField = xCoordForTextField+10;
        [aButton addSubview:textField];
        [aButton bringSubviewToFront:textField];

        if(count == 9){
            xCoord=54;
            xCoordForCart=230;
            xCoordForTextField = 230;

        }
    }else if (count >9 && count<=12){
        yCoord=buttonHeight+buttonHeight+buttonHeight+buttonGap+60;
        aButton.frame= CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
        xCoord=xCoord+323;

        //for cart button
        yCoordForCart=buttonHeightForCart+buttonHeightForCart+buttonGapForCart-30;
        aButtonForCart.frame= CGRectMake(xCoordForCart, yCoordForCart,buttonWidthForCart,buttonHeightForCart);
        xCoordForCart=xCoordForCart+2;

        //for textField
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordForTextField+50,yCoordForTextField,WidthForTextField,HeightForTextField);
        xCoordForTextField = xCoordForTextField+10;
        [aButton addSubview:textField];
        [aButton bringSubviewToFront:textField];

        if(count == 12){
            xCoord=54;
            xCoordForCart=230;
            xCoordForTextField = 230;

        }

    }
    count++;
    [aButton setTag:i];
    [aButtonForCart setTag:i];
    [aButtonForCart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cart_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imgNames objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton addSubview:aButtonForCart];
    [self.scrollViewForCatlogView addSubview:aButton];

    //selectors
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(itemButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButtonForCart addTarget:self action:@selector(cartButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
[self.scrollViewForCatlogView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(900, yCoord+buttonHeight)];
}
```

I have seen these questions but they weren't useful in my case

1) [dynamically create multiple TextFields based on array.length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880323/dynamically-create-multiple-textfields-based-on-array-length)

2) [Add UItextfield on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643907/add-uitextfield-on-button-click)

Comment: Well, you actually create the UITextField only once, outside the for loop. The buttons are created within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like Christian stated, all your buttons use the same pointer declared outside your loop. When you do

```
[self.scrollViewForCatlogView addSubview:aButton];
```

the same pointer is added 12 times, and only the last button will be displayed.

You must declare a new pointer for each view you want to display, like this :

```
for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIButton *aButtonForCart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
}
```

It is probably the same for your UITextField.

Comment: Yup thanku for the help. That was the issue. I solved it by initializing the textField within the for loop.